# How can I rename parameter in action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an action:

```
 public JsonResult IsAwesome(string value){...}
```

But in my form this parameter looks like "**ViewModelName.SomePropValue**" and I cant change it there.
How to make it work so that the value from 'ViewModelName.SomePropValue' was in the '**value**' action parameter.

For example:

```
<input name="ViewModelName.SomePropValue" value="MYDATA" />

public JsonResult IsAwesome(string value){
      value=="MYDATA"; 
}
```

Comment: You told us that you can't change the propvalue name, maybe you can change the action parameter name ?

Comment: You about it?

public JsonResult IsAwesome(string ViewModelName.SomePropValue)

Comment: Haha, you are right that would be "weird" :P

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use a `FormModel` class so that the model binder can bind to each property.. 
So in your case your form will take a ViewModel input

```
class ViewModel
{
  public FormModel FormModel{get;set;}
}
public class FormModel
{
  public string SomePropValue{get;set;}
}
public void action(ViewModel FormViewModel)
```

**Another option** is to use a partial view.

In your View taking the ViewModel, render a partial:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("Form",Model.FormModel)
```

In the rendered patial view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.SomePropValue);
```

Which means your action can now take a `FormModel` object:

```
public void action(FormModel formModel)
```

Comment: It still doesn't give me ability to do this:
public class FormModel
{
  public string ViewModelName.SomePropValue{get;set;}
}

Comment: Especially the top part if you don't want to use a PartialView